# gcloud does not skip root level files

Tags: google-app-engine, single-page-application, gcloud, google-cloud-sdk

I am trying to deploy an SPA to GAE. I am following the configuration sample as given in their [static website example](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/getting-started/hosting-a-static-website). My project folder structure is as follows:

```
D:\Projects\Proj1
    |-node_modules
    |-src
    |-www
    |-.babelrc
    |-.gitignore
    |-app.yaml
    |-package.json
    |-package-lock.json
```

and my app.yaml is as follows:

```
runtime: php55
service: frontend
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /
  static_files: www/index.html
  upload: www/index.html

- url: /(.*)
  static_files: www/\1
  upload: www/(.*)
```

The project output is built to the `www` folder. `gcloud` is used for deploying using `gcloud app deploy app.yaml --quiet --version %DOC_VERSION% --project %GCP_PROJECT_ID%` command from a batch file.

I was expecting `gcloud` to copy and deploy files that were only under `www` folder, but instead it started copying aprox 10K files which were under the `node_modules` folder as well (I terminated the process).

So, I changed the `app.yaml` and now it looks like this:

```
runtime: php55
service: frontend
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true
skip_files:
    - ^node_modules$
    - ^src$
    - ^assets$
    - ^\.

handlers:
- url: /
  static_files: www/index.html
  upload: www/index.html

- url: /(.*)
  static_files: www/\1
  upload: www/(.*)
```

And works as expected.

My understanding was that the `static_files` setting was used by the `gcloud` tool for uploading relevant files. So, why was it uploading the files from non-mentioned folder? Is mentioning `skip_files` is the only way to properly address this behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `static_files` setting in your app.yaml file only specifies the directory as the location for static files, for the platform to locate them when needed at runtime.

To specify which directory and files should or shouldn't be uploaded during deployment, defining `skip_files` in the app.yaml is one option. The other option is to create a `.gcloudignore` file at the root of your project (where the app.yaml is located) where you specify files that should *not* be uploaded to Google Cloud Platform. It follows the same syntax as `.gitignore`. You'll find an example of it in the Github sample code [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/php-docs-samples/blob/master/appengine/php72/logging/.gcloudignore). Note that you may use `skip_files` OR `.gcloudignore` to avoid conflicts.

Comment: Note that the `.gcloudignore` approach is a bit more restrictive than the `skip_files` one: it only works with newer Cloud SDK versions and doesn't work with the language-specific GAE SDKs.

Comment: So, it looks like it would be easier to copy the app.yaml to the final distribution folder and deploy from there.